# menuBar() in PyQt5

Tags: python, menu, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to load a menubar onto my gui, but my class object has no attribute for self.menuBar(). Can someone help me, no tutorials seem to offer any way around.

```
class EmailBlast(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        bar = QtWidgets.menuBar() 
        file_menu = bar.addMenu('File')
        file_edit = bar.addMenu('Edit')
```

Error message:

```
File "BasicEmail.py", line 84, in email_config
self.ui = EmailBlast()
File "BasicEmail.py", line 96, in __init__
self.menuBar()
AttributeError: 'EmailBlast' object has no attribute 'menuBar'
```

What am I missing here.

Updated project:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.email_blast_widget = EmailBlast()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.email_blast_widget)
    bar = self.menuBar()
    file_file = bar.addMenu('File')         
    file_edit = bar.addMenu('Edit') 

class EmailBlast(QtWidgets.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.text_box = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
    self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Save')
    self.clear_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Clear')        
    self.open_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open')        
    self.init_ui()
```

Answer (score 13):

Exception speaks truth: `QWidget` class does not have a `menuBar` attribute, [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) has (as well as toolbars and status bar):

[image: QMainWindow layout]

If you have `QMainWindow` instance somewhere in your code and just want to fill menu items in `EmailBlast` init, you can get menu bar of mentioned `QMainWindow` by calling `bar = QtWidgets.QMainWindow.menuBar()`. Menus consists of an `QAction`s so you probably need to add them too.

If you do not have `QMainWindow` then consider adding one. `QMainWindow` must have "Central Widget". In your case it is probably `EmailBlast` widget. Since `EmailBlast` will be a part of `MainWindow` you need to create and show `MainWindow` instance instead of `EmailBlast`.

If you have multiple elements (buttons, text edits etc.) in `EmailBlast` widget then Qt [layout system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) comes into play almost inevitable (quickly glance at pics in docs to grasp a concept).

It can be pretty hard to wrap a head around all this things at once, so once again.

**QMainWindow** - central part of your app. Has menu bar, toolbars, status bar and central area occupied by *central widget*.

**Central widget** - a widget providing main functionality of your app (or it can be a widget holding other widgets like [QSplitter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html)). In your case it is probably a `EmailBlast` widget.

**EmailBlast** widget provides a piece of (reusable) functionality. To do so it itself consists of various helper widgets (text edits, buttons, check boxes and so on). To place this small widgets in a predictable manner the *layout* is created. Widgets are placed inside layout and layout is set to `EmailBlast` widget.

**Menu bar** consists of zero or more [QMenu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html)s, which in turn can have [QAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html)s. QAction signals (usually `triggered`) are connecting to slots to provide desired behavior.

Here is a complete example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # creating EmailBlast widget and setting it as central
        self.email_blast_widget = EmailBlast(parent=self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.email_blast_widget)
        # filling up a menu bar
        bar = self.menuBar()
        # File menu
        file_menu = bar.addMenu('File')
        # adding actions to file menu
        open_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Open', self)
        close_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Close', self)
        file_menu.addAction(open_action)
        file_menu.addAction(close_action)
        # Edit menu
        edit_menu = bar.addMenu('Edit')
        # adding actions to edit menu
        undo_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Undo', self)
        redo_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Redo', self)
        edit_menu.addAction(undo_action)
        edit_menu.addAction(redo_action)

        # use `connect` method to bind signals to desired behavior
        close_action.triggered.connect(self.close)


class EmailBlast(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # create and set layout to place widgets
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        self.text_box = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Save')
        self.clear_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Clear')
        self.open_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open')
        # add widgets to layout. Params are:
        # (widget, fromRow, fromColumn, rowSpan=1, columnSpan=1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.text_box, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.save_button, 1, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.clear_button, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.open_button, 1, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # creating main window
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code produces nice little app like that:

[image: app window]

Comment: I recommend you place the widgets inside a layout, and place this layout inside the centralWidget.

Comment: The idea is to help the author of the question, if you put code that does not work will confuse the author. Another option is to remove that part and display the necessary code.

Comment: @eyllanesc, fair point. I tried to update answer to minimize confusion.

Comment: @Mikhail the code works great and is clearly the correct way to do it. However, my menu buttons still won't show up.

Comment: @MikhailKnyazev, Thank you for explaining the concept of window vs frame. However, I can't seem to get the buttons to appear. Could you take a look at new code?

Comment: @EwokHugz, I was confused by `self.init_ui()` function. I thought that all actual interface is already created inside it. I updated answer with complete example now, hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: @9dogs Interesting. It still does not show the menu bar on my GUI. Does it make a difference I am using a mac? All the buttons are fine, but there's no menu bar or even an "invisible" one, the text box goes straight to the top...

Comment: @9dogs I just needed to look up. The menubar is there. Thank you for your help.